# When i inputed values for elements in array, in for loop, after for loop them transformed

Tags: c, arrays

When i print `baza[nlines]` in `for` loop, result("outprint") is correct, it print what i inputed. But when i checked "outprint" after `for` loop, it somehow transform and both elements of `baza[]` is same. Example: i inputed for `number_loops` 2, for `baza[0]` "grass", and for `baza[1]` "beer", so when i printed it after `for` loop, `baza[0]` somehow become  same, like `baza[1]` , and it has been printing for both "beer".

```
int number_loops = 2;
char *baza[SIZE];
char baza_pojedinac[100];
char p[1000];
int nlines = 0;
for ( ;number_loops-- > 0 ; )
{
    getline(baza_pojedinac);
    baza_pojedinac[strlen(baza_pojedinac)-1] = '\0';
    strcpy(p, baza_pojedinac);

    baza[nlines] = p;
    printf("baza: %s\n",baza[nlines]);
    nlines++;

}

printf("first: %s\n",baza[0]); // result == "beer".
printf("second: %s\n",baza[1]); // result == "beer".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `for` loop both `baza[0]` and `baza[1]` point to the same string `p[]`, so they have to be the same thing. When you do `baza[nlines] = p;` you don't copy the string, you only say that `baza[nlines]` is now pointing to `p`.

There are a few ways to fix this, but the easiest is to just make `baza` a 2D array and copy the string into it:

```
char baza[10][SIZE];     //Increase if needing more than 10 lines
char baza_pojedinac[100];
int nlines = 0;

for ( ;number_loops-- > 0 ; )
{
    getline(baza_pojedinac);

    strcpy(baza[nlines], baza_pojedinac);
    printf("baza: %s\n",baza[nlines]);
    nlines++;

}

printf("first: %s\n",baza[0]);
printf("second: %s\n",baza[1]);
```

**Edit** 
If you'd like to allocate strings instead you can do:

```
char* baza[SIZE]; 
char baza_pojedinac[100];
int nlines = 0;

for ( ;number_loops-- > 0 ; )
{
    getline(baza_pojedinac);

    baza[nlines] = malloc(100);
    strcpy(baza[nlines], baza_pojedinac);

    printf("baza: %s\n", baza[nlines]);
    nlines++;

}

printf("first: %s\n",baza[0]);
printf("second: %s\n",baza[1]);
...
free(baza[0]);   // Don't forget to free the memory eventually
free(baza[1]);
```

Comment: I'm not good very well with malloc and other function for allocating memory, but will be this helping somewhat?
(p = malloc(100))

Comment: Pretty close, see my edit for how to allocate memory for each string.

Comment: @uesp can you help me understand why in OP's question, the printf print out grass instead of beer? Isn't in the 2nd loop p's value is overwritten to beer already? So both baza[0], and baza[1] should be beer? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it should print out the last string entered and I was assuming it was either a typo or an error on behalf of the poster. Feel free to try it yourself (I did confirm it does print the last string entered).

Comment: Sorry i mess up @SSC, it should be both baza[0] and baza[1] "beer", but i confused it... Edited

Comment: Why is necessary to free(baza[0])?

Comment: For everything you `malloc()` you have to eventually `free()` or you will have memory leaks and possibly run out of memory.